# Segmentation fault when passing char

Tags: c, netbeans

This is part of my main function, I'm passing the char array into the get file_file(file) function.

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    char file[60];
    get_file(file);
    return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

This is the get file method that I have made. I just want it to return 'file' back to the main method to be passed into multiple other methods but I'm getting the segmentation fault straight after the scanf statement according to debugging.

```
    void get_file(char file) {
        printf("What file do you want?");
        scanf(" %s",file);
//do other stuff
    return file;
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`file` is an array in `main()`. You have to receive it with a `pointer to char` variable, because an `array` decays into a `pointer` when it is sent to a function.

Use something like this,

```
void get_file(char* file)
```

---

Another problem in your code is the return type. If you want to return something from the function, you need to change its return type(it should not be `void`) and receive it in the calling function.

In your case, you do not need to return `file`, as the input is stored in the address sent to the function.

Be aware though, that you need to specify the size of the string to be read, else it can cause buffer overflow.

```
scanf(" %59s",file);
```

Comment: Will the `return` work if the function is using `void`?

Answer (score 3):

A `char` array *decays* (implicitly converted when passed to a function) to a **pointer**, not a `char`. Define `get_line` like

```
void get_file(char* file) {
    ...
}
```

instead.

One `char` can only hold one character, so a buffer overflow would occur. Also, `sizeof(char*)` usually is greater than `sizeof(char) == 1`, so the address is truncated and probably turns into an invalid address.
The compiler actually should've issued some warning, though.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the * in the `get_file` declaration. You want to pass the pointer to the array, not the value for the positon itself. That way, you should type

```
 void get_file(char* file)
```